# How can you dynamically add more tabs to a tabgroup in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I basically need a way to add new tabs to a tabgroup in Matlab on demand. So the user can upload many "modules" using my GUI, but when they click run in my GUI I want to be able to show tabular data of all individual modules using tabs. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: It's pretty clearly stated in the documentation... You add a [`uitab`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitab.html) to the parent [`uitabgroup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitabgroup.html)

Comment: The point of stack overflow is to create documentation. See meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343704/1810205

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new [`uitab`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitab.html?refresh=true) and add it to the existing [`uitabgroup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitabgroup.html?refresh=true). Here is a minimal example of how you could do this programmatically in a button callback.

```
function maketabs()
    hfig = figure;

    %// Create the tabgroup to hold all tabs
    tabs = uitabgroup('Parent', hfig, 'Position', [0.2 0 0.8 1]);

    %// Create the button to add a new tab
    uicontrol('String', 'Add Tab', ...
               'Units', 'Normalized', ...
               'Callback', @(s,e)addTabCallback(tabs), ...
               'Position', [0 0.5 0.2 0.1]);

    function addTabCallback(parent)
        %// Figure out how many tabs there already are
        ntabs = numel(findall(parent, 'type', 'uitab'));

        %// Create a new uitab in this group
        uitab('Parent', parent, 'Title', sprintf('Tab %d', ntabs+1));
    end
end
```